# No se loguea aunque datos sean correctos - PHP

Tags: php, login

Tengo un formulario para "login" del cliente.

Con dos campos: usuario y contraseña.

**¿La sintaxis de la conexión a la base de datos es correcta?**

```
 $conexion = mysqli_connect("mysql:host=localhost", "1718d0_osmar", "1718d0_osmar", "1718d0_osmar");
```

**¿Por qué siempre me sale "¡Sus datos no son correctos!" aunque los datos que introduzco son correctos?**

**Código HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Formulario de Login - Cliente</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_iniciar_sesion.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo2.jpg">
        <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="logueo_cliente.php" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="return validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente();">
            <h2>CLIENTE</h2>
            <h4>INICIAR SESIÓN</h4>
            <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1">
            <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2">
            <div id="mensaje" align="center">
                <?php if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 'true'): ?>
                    <h4><p style="color:red;">¡Sus datos no son correctos!</p></h4>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div id="iniciar" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"><br/>
                <p class="form-link">¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? <a href="registrar.php">Regístrate aquí</a></p><br/>
                <p class="form-link"><a href="recuperar_contrasena.php">He olvidado mi contraseña</a></p><br/><hr/><br/>
                <p class="form-link"><img src="imagenes/entrar.jpg" height="10px" width="10px" alt="invitado"/>&nbsp;<a href="index.php">Entrar como invitado</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php
    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();

    //Guardamos el valor de los campos <input> del formulario en variables.
    $idemail = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    //Nos conectamos a la base de datos.
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("mysql:host=localhost", "1718d0_osmar", "1718d0_osmar", "1718d0_osmar");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE idemail='".$idemail."' and password='".$password."'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    //Guardamos la cantidad de filas que hemos obtenido de la consulta.
    $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

    //Si existen filas...
    if($filas>0){
        //Hay un cliente logueado correctamente y cargamos "index.php".
        $_SESSION["cliente"] = $idemail;
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        header("Location: iniciar_sesion_cliente.php?error=true");
    }

    //Libera la memoria del resultado.
    mysqli_free_result($resultado);

    //Cierra la conexión.
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Los parámetros de conexión son: host, usuario, contraseña y base de datos, ¿Son estos tus datos correctos? ¿La consulta te regresa datos si la ejecutas desde la consola SQL o PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Sí, si la ejecuto desde consola SQL sí me devuelve el dato correcto.

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo esa syntaxis de host es para PDO, además de estar incompleta (`mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname'`) solo deja ese parámetro como `localhost` y debería de funcionar la conexión

Comment: Q onda? fijate mi sentencia de coneccion tiene sintaxis diferente. "Database=formatilat;Data Source=localhost;User Id=matiasrama;Password=*****"

Answer (score 1):

Varios problemas con el código:

**Revisa que se haya conectado la base:**

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "1718d0_osmar", "1718d0_osmar", "1718d0_osmar");

if(!$conexion){
 exit("Error!!" . mysqli_connect_error() );
}
```

**¡¡Escapa tus inputs!!!:**

```
$idemail= mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['email']);
$password= mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['password']);
```

**No necesitas una variable para un valor que usarás una sola vez**

**No necesitas declarar tus variables explícitamente cuando el string es delimitado por `""`**

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE idemail='$idemail' AND password='$password';");
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
    $_SESSION["cliente"] = $idemail;
    header("Location: index.php"); 

} else{
    //header("Location: iniciar_sesion_cliente.php?error=true"); //probablemente el problema está en el query
    echo "El query es SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE idemail='$idemail' AND password='$password';";
    exit();
}
```

Si tienes problemas todavía, ejecuta ese query directo en la base de datos con el cliente de tu preferencia (phpmyadmin, navicat, etc.) para que puedas ver el resultado del query. Es probable que los datos no sean correctos.

Espero esto ayude.